# Log in works after second attempt on owin

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, cookies, owin

I update windows server 16 from 2.2.1 to 2.8.0. After update log in start work strange:
on first attempt it create ASP.NET_SessionId and redirect back to log in page;
on second it generate .AspNet.ApplicationCookie.

But, when I try to reproduce it on my local machine and on AWS instance (just open site using IIS) it not reproduced

Also I have problems with log out but it didn`t work as well it doesn't work at all

I try change version of Windows server to older and I have no this problems on 2.2.1 and 2.3.1 but from 5.3.1 this problem appears

P.S.: I use Owin for Authentication

Comment: can you post some code? (how you configured OWIN and securtity?)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.